# octave cannot load file

Tags: loading, octave

I failed to load .txt files and .dat files in my octave.

When I use the code 'load test.dat'
the terminal said:
-bash: load: command not found

and I tried load('test.dat'). The terminal said:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'test.dat''

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to enter Octave commands into a shell (bash in your case). You've to start Octave first with "octave" or "octave --no-gui" in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

data = load('test.dat')

what are you trying to view though?